# Do notifications attached to a recurring event in Google Calendar get sent each time the event recurs?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I create an event in Google Calendar that recurs every two weeks. I added notifications for one week before and one day before. Then I invited a bunch of people to the event.

a) When I create the event with notifications, are those notifications only for me, or do they do to the whole group I invited?

b) Do the notifications go every time the event recurs, or just for the first one?